# Delete - I can't specify target table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

Why this query doesn't work?

```
DELETE FROM recent_edits 
WHERE trackid NOT IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT history.trackid 
     FROM history JOIN recent_edits ON history.trackid=recent_edits.trackid 
     GROUP BY recent_edits.trackid)
```

I get this message : "You can't specify target table "recent_edits" for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Try in this way

```
DELETE FROM recent_edits 
WHERE trackid NOT IN 
     (select * from (SELECT DISTINCT history.trackid 
     FROM history JOIN recent_edits ON history.trackid=recent_edits.trackid 
     GROUP BY recent_edits.trackid) as t);
```

Comment: This needs an explanation.

Comment: @nhaarman a detailed explanation: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql

Comment: @fall That link has rotten. Here's the archived version https://web.archive.org/web/20160413115107/https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql

Answer (score 38):

You can't post-process a table which is locked for deletion. using the hack `select * from (query)` as Nicola states will generate a temporary table instead of direct access.

Edit - make sure that you give ID to the tables you use since it is nested and will require uniqueID for every table.