# MySQL delete row if id is found in another row

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

In a table where there is a `subscriber_id` and a `letter_id`, a subscriber might be subscribed to more than one letter. I want to unsubscribe people from a certain letter if they are subscribed to ANY other letter. I need help building a query. I've seen what I might call nested queries before but I'm not experienced in writing them.

I could probably do this in PHP by first querying like:
`SELECT subscriber_id FROM subscriptions WHERE letter_id=3`
then run a foreach on the result and delete where a subscriber_id has more than one match, but I'd bet MySQL can do this a lot faster if I only knew how.

I tried to write pseudo code here, but I get hung up even on that.

In case it helps, each row also has its own id.

Comment: An honest and well-worded question deserves an answer ;-) Unfortunately I don't know how (yet) but I'm sure someone will be kind enough to help out.

Comment: if they cant be subscribed to more than one, you should have a unique key on (subscriber_id,letter_id) then the issue could never arise

Comment: @Dagon, They can subscribe to multiple letters. This letter is an exception. It's too general. Once they are subscribed to at least one specific letter, I need to take them out of the general one. The database is part of an application and my script is interacting with it in a way that the developer probably did not expect, so I need to be very careful about what changes I make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE FROM subscriptions WHERE letter_id=3 AND subscriber_id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT subscriber_id FROM subscriptions WHERE letter_id<>3) AS x)`

Comment: **Delete - I can't specify target table**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816840/delete-i-cant-specify-target-table

Comment: This looks like it's probably the right one. I'll test it carefully and let you know. :) Thanks.

Comment: @dianuj I did get that error. Thanks for the link. I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: I didn't exactly follow why, but if you wrap the sub-query in `(select * from` and `as x)` then it works.

Answer (score 0):

The query to figure out who has more than one "other" letter (in this case `letter_id` 3) goes like this:

```
SELECT subscriber_id
FROM subscriptions
WHERE letter_id <> 3
GROUP BY subscriber_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Join this to your delete query, add the `letter_id = 3` condition, and you should be all set:

```
DELETE FROM subscriptions
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT subscriber_id
  FROM subscriptions
  WHERE letter_id <> 3
  GROUP BY subscriber_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) MoreThan1 ON subscriptions.subscriber_id = MoreThan1.subscriber_id
WHERE letter_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has a Primary Key (i.e. `id` with auto increment):

```
DELETE n1 FROM `table` n1, `table` n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.`field` = n2.`field`
```

Where `table` is your table name, and `field` is the field to test.

I adapted my query from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql). If your table doesn't have a primary ID table, you can [add it to an existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are asking something like this,

```
DELETE FROM subscriptions 
WHERE subscriber_id = (SELECT subscriber_id FROM subscriptions WHERE letter_id=3);
```

Comment: **Delete - I can't specify target table**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816840/delete-i-cant-specify-target-table